# Limit over multivariables and differentiation

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function at $0$.

We look for
$$
\lim_{x,y\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}
$$

Do we have ($h=x-y$):
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} = \frac{f(y+h)-f(y)}{h} \longrightarrow_{h,y\rightarrow 0} f'(0)
$$

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not always true. For example consider the function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x}) & \text{if } x \neq 0,\\
0 & \text{if } x = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
It can be verified that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, and that
$$
f'(x) = 
\begin{cases}
2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x}) & \text{if } x \neq 0,\\
0 & \text{if } x = 0.
\end{cases}
$$
The limit of interest is however not defined. If it would be defined, we could namely take the limit over the line x = 2y, and see that the limit would have to equal
$$
\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{4y^2 \sin\left(\frac{1}{2y}\right) - y^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)}{y^2} = \lim_{y \to 0} \left(4\sin\left(\frac{1}{2y}\right) - \sin\left(\frac{1}{y}\right)\right),
$$
which is not defined.

Comment: we can write
$f(x)-f(y) = \int_x^y f'(t) dt = (x-y) \int_0^1 f'(x+(y-x)u)\,du$.

So the limit would be : $\int_0^1f'(0)\, du=f'(0)$.

Applying this method to your function, where does the problem appear ? Is it always possible to commute $\int$ and $\lim$ ?

Comment: @Smilia it is not always possible to interchange the limit and the integral. However, even if you could, you also use that $\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x) = f'(0)$, which is not the case in the given example ($f'$ is not continuous). I think it might be possible to show that if $f'$ would be continuous in 0, then the answer to your problem would be $f'(0)$, however, I have not verified this.